# Прыжок можно повторить до приземления

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я добавил в свой проект механику прыжка, реализованную вот так:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
   rb.AddForce(0, JumpPower * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

Проблема заключается в том, что можно прыгнуть до того как игрок приземлится, тем самым поднимаясь слишком высоко. Я бы хотел это исправить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно заводят либо булеву переменную, либо метод `IsGrounded`, который отвечает за то, чтобы возвращать булево значение, что персонаж приземлился. Соответственно в других методах идёт проверка `if (!IsGrounded()) { return; }` или наоборот `if (IsGrounded()) { КАКАЯ-ТО ЛОГИКА }`

Как будет реализован этот самый метод - зависит от вас самих. Например должно отслеживаться, что коллайдер игрока вошёл в триггер земли или в объект с тегом `ground` и т.д.